# Using single Handlebars function multiple times for multiple data sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Is there a way to reuse single Handlebars function multiple times, each time feeding it with different data?

I've got a two divs acting as a buttons of following code

```
<div id="#btn-A" data-one="data-A1" data-two="data-A2" onclick="magicHappensHere(this)">
<div id="#btn-B" data-one="data-B1" data-two="data-B2" onclick="magicHappensHere(this)">
```

and two functions

```
function magicHappensHere(data) {
    //some code
    var selection = $('#selection');
    selection.append('<div id="target-" + data.one + '" class="target"></div>'
    buildTemplate(data);
    //some more code
}
```

and there is the actual template call

```
function buildTemplate(data) {
    try {
        var source = $('#source').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(data);
        $('.target').html(html);
    } catch(err) {

    }
}
```

And it works fine up to a certain moment. I can add both target divs, they have different ids and all is cool up until now. The problem is, even though as a outcome i have target-A and target-B, the data displayed in both is data from target-B. I'm almost sure there's some kind of problem with my `buildTemplate` function and I should look there. What I figured is that `data` is overwriting itself and it shouldn't. Can any of you, good people tell me, how to avoid this?

Comment: Check to see if the call to $('.target') grabs both target-A and target-B.  You may need to make it more specific to which target you are trying to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `buildTemplate` function you assign the resulting HTML to any div with the class `target`. Try assigning the HTML by ID. Here's a helper function:

```
function renderData(template, data, selector) {
    var html = template(data);
    $(selector).html(html);
}
```

And now we can easily render data to different elements (I'm assuming we've already constructed the handlebars template):

```
renderData(template, data1, '#first-target');
renderData(template, data2, '#second-target');
```